# Compile/load time weaving with spring

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) explain that, the LTW has to enabled either through the use of     `<context:load-time-weaver/>` xml instruction or the use of `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` annotation. However, I have done neither, but I still see that aspects are woven correctly in my projects!

1. In this case, I don't think they are woven at compile-time (but are they?), so it's surely got to be load-time-weaving?
2. Even if that's the case, how does it automatically choose to weave aspects in during load-time? Shouldn't the aspects remain unwoven if they are not turned on using one of the ways mentioned above as the docs say?
3. I've got the aspectj-weaver in my classpath, but that can't be enough to choose either of these weaving types anyway, can it?

Comment: Have you actually created or imported AspectJ aspects that require weaving?  Spring AOP features like @Transactional work just fine with run-time proxying, no weaving is required.

Comment: Hmm, is there a list of aspects that do and don't require weaving that I can look at? I've only used logging aspect with `around` type advice in my project.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean. My use of `aspectj-autoproxy` would have done it for me through runtime proxying so aspects didn't need to need woven at compile/load time. Am I correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Spring AOP** does not rely on **AspectJ** byte code weaving.  It just borrows the annotations used to define aspects from the AspectJ project.  It is a separately implemented framework that uses run-time proxies to implement aspects.  If you have `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` in your application context then spring is using proxies to implement supported aspects defined on beans that are in the container.

Proxies can only achieve a sub-set of the full capabilities of the actual **AspectJ** system, basically advice that wraps methods. Due to their nature proxies have following limitations:

- interception on external calls only *(while breaching proxy boundary)*
- interception on `public` members only (`private`/`protected` can't be intercepted)
- unawareness to local calls (or calls with `this` or `super`)

If you want to be able to advise fields for example, you would need to enable the use of [Native AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Comment: Great! But through the use of the asectj-maven-plugin, I can achieve compile time weaving. Or through `<context:load-time-weaver />` for that matter. Will that mean one of these weaving techniques will manage to trump `<aop:aspectj:autoproxy />` and be used instead of runtime proxying?

Comment: This section of the manual describes how to configure when you have both Spring AOP and AspectJ runtime in the same project: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-configure

Comment: If you configured the same aspect for both weaving and proxy.... I guess it would execute twice?  have honestly never tried :)

Comment: It didn't, it ran only once. So I'm assuming the proxy would have trumped, no matter the target was woven with aspect or not. It can't have cared to check if the target was woven at all IMO.