# How to configure Spring AOP to use AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to use AOP concept to time execution time of some methods that I mark with an annotation that I created. My problem however is that I refer to the annotated method internally, from within the same class. For example:

```
public void login(params) {
    some logic ... 
    performLogin();
    some logic ...
}

@Measured
public void performLogin() {
     some logic ...
}
```

This is a known issue caused by the fact that Spring AOP is using proxy based approach that does not "see" the internal calls within the same class. Apparently I can solve this situation by using AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. If I understand correctly, it can be configured from within Spring itself. From what I found, it looks like I should include `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation to configure Spring to use AspectJ instead of its own AOP. Unfortunately, it did not help and after adding the annotation, the interception of the annotated method did not occur.

There is a lot of [information](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-using-aspectj) on this topic in Spring reference documentation and I got a bit lost. Is there anything else I am supposed to do so that AspectJ will be used?

**P.S.** Please note that I cannot refactor the whole class and move the calling method outside.

**P.P.S.** I also verified my pointcut configuration. I annotated the calling method which is invoked externally and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies can only achieve a sub-set of the full capabilities of the actual **AspectJ** system, basically advice that wraps methods. Due to their nature proxies have following limitations:

- interception on external calls only (while breaching proxy boundary)
- interception on public members only (private/protected can't be intercepted)
  unawareness to local calls (or calls with this or super)

`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` is not enough - it only wraps methods, you need something like this: `<context:load-time-weaver/>`

If you want to be able to advise fields for example, you would need to enable the use of [Native AspectJ](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I am trying to do. Just struggling with the configuration.

Comment: If you are using java configuration, try add `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` for configuration, also check link to Native AspectJs in my answer

Comment: or use compile time weaving

Comment: check also that you have aspectjweaver.jar in your project.

Comment: I guess you could have simply share a link to this answer in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21473111/1119381